# Как заставить блоки равномерно сжиматься и растягиваться?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, чтобы 4 блока с новостями равномерно растянулись на ширину контейнера 980 px и равномерно сужались до критической точки в 760 px. C inline-block не получается. Как это лучше сделать?

```css
      body{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .container{
            max-width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin:0;
            
        }
        .image{
            max-width: 980px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        img{
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        header{
            min-width:100%;
            background-color:#c2c2c2;
            margin:0;
        }
        .news_block{
            min-width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .block{
            width:170px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top:20px;
               
        }
        button{
            width:170px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
        button:hover{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        h1{
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
            padding:20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
       .main{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
       }
        .news{
            padding:5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .description{
            margin:0;
            padding:20px 125px 30px 120px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#68a4c4;
            color:white;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .copyright{
            margin:0;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 760px) {
       
       .main{
          max-width:100%;  
          margin:0 auto;
       }
       .block{
          width:95%;
          height:170px;
          background-color:#f8f8f8;   
          margin-right: 0;
      } 
     
      button{
          width:100%;
          height:40px;
          border:none;
          position:absolute;
          left:0px;
          top:130px;
          background-color:#68a4c4 ;
          color:white;
          font-weight: bold;
      
      }
  
      .description{
          width:95%;
          margin:0;
          padding:10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body{
          position:relative;
      }
      header{
          width:100%;
    }

      footer{
          width:100%;
      }
      img{
          width:90%;
          height:auto;
      }
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="cat">
        </div>
    
        <header><h1>Новости для котиков</h1></header>
        <div class="news_block">
            <div class="block "><p class="main">Новость 1</p><p class="news">Кому-то еще инресно узнать про короновирус?</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 2</p><p class="news">Отменили минский полумарафон, зря готовились</p>
             <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "> <p class="main">Новость 3</p><p class="news">Куда пойти на выходных когда нет денег?</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 4</p><p class="news">Погода испортилась, а чего вы хотели от Сентября</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <p class="description">
            <span>Что такое Lorem ipsum?</span><br>
            <br>Для заполнения страницы в веб-дизайне используют специально сгенерированный бессмысленный текст, получивший название Lorem ipsum. Перевод данной фразы в таком виде отсутствует, это искаженная цитата из труда Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного на латыни. Данное словосочетание — обрезка фразы «Dolorem ipsum», которая переводится как «саму боль».<br>
            <br><span>Почему он используется?</span><br>
            Использовать данный текст в книгопечатании начали еще 500 лет назад, чтобы продемонстрировать различные шрифты и внешний вид страницы заказчику. Благодаря такому заполнителю было видно, сколько строчек помещается на странице, подходит ли дизайн шрифтов для данной книги.<br>
            <br><span>Откуда он появился?</span><br>
            В самом деле, волшебные слова Lorem ipsum известны многим из тех, кто работает в области полиграфии или же веб-дизайна. Более того, эта абракадабра — только начало большого текста, и существуют программы, которые сгенерируют продолжение якобы бессмыслицы на псевдолатыни, выдав необходимое число символов, абзацев или параграфов. Для чего? Только для того, чтобы заполнить место текстом, похожим на обычный текст, изображенным латинским алфавитом, но внимания читателя не отвлекающим. <br>
            <br><span>Откуда его взять?</span><br>
            Такую штуку специалисты по дизайну называют «рыбой». И хотя сейчас Lorem ipsum используют главным образом специалисты по веб-дизайну, придумана эта «рыба» была еще в 16-м веке книгопечатниками для демонстрации шрифтов различных форм и размеров. Чтобы заказчик видел, как будет выглядеть печатная страница, сколько на ней окажется строчек и подходит ли используемый шрифт для цели, с которой печатается заказываемая книга. Вот печатники взяли длинный латинский текст и применили для презентации.</p>
        </div>
        <footer><p class="copyright"> &copy; Копирайт 2017</p></footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить медиа-запрос `@media only screen and (min-width: 761px)` с `max-width` и `width` в полную ширину для `.block`. А дальше в брейкпоинте в `760px` его заменит нижний медиа-запрос, который у вас был.

```css
body{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .container{
            max-width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin:0;
            
        }
        .image{
            max-width: 980px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        img{
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        header{
            min-width:100%;
            background-color:#c2c2c2;
            margin:0;
        }
        .news_block{
            min-width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .block{
            width:170px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
            position:relative;
            margin-top:20px;
               
        }
        button{
            width:170px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
        button:hover{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        h1{
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
            padding:20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
       .main{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
       }
        .news{
            padding:5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .description{
            margin:0;
            padding:20px 125px 30px 120px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#68a4c4;
            color:white;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .copyright{
            margin:0;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
        @media only screen and (min-width: 761px) {
        .block {
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 980px;
        }
      }
        @media (max-width: 760px) {
       
       .main{
          max-width:100%;  
          margin:0 auto;
       }
       .block{
          width:95%;
          height:170px;
          background-color:#f8f8f8;   
          margin-right: 0;
      } 
     
      button{
          width:100%;
          height:40px;
          border:none;
          position:absolute;
          left:0px;
          top:130px;
          background-color:#68a4c4 ;
          color:white;
          font-weight: bold;
      
      }
  
      .description{
          width:95%;
          margin:0;
          padding:10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body{
          position:relative;
      }
      header{
          width:100%;
    }

      footer{
          width:100%;
      }
      img{
          width:90%;
          height:auto;
      }
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="cat">
        </div>
    
        <header><h1>Новости для котиков</h1></header>
        <div class="news_block">
            <div class="block "><p class="main">Новость 1</p><p class="news">Кому-то еще инресно узнать про короновирус?</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 2</p><p class="news">Отменили минский полумарафон, зря готовились</p>
             <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "> <p class="main">Новость 3</p><p class="news">Куда пойти на выходных когда нет денег?</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
            <div class="block "><p class="main"> Новость 4</p><p class="news">Погода испортилась, а чего вы хотели от Сентября</p>
                <button>Читать дальше</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <p class="description">
            <span>Что такое Lorem ipsum?</span><br>
            <br>Для заполнения страницы в веб-дизайне используют специально сгенерированный бессмысленный текст, получивший название Lorem ipsum. Перевод данной фразы в таком виде отсутствует, это искаженная цитата из труда Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного на латыни. Данное словосочетание — обрезка фразы «Dolorem ipsum», которая переводится как «саму боль».<br>
            <br><span>Почему он используется?</span><br>
            Использовать данный текст в книгопечатании начали еще 500 лет назад, чтобы продемонстрировать различные шрифты и внешний вид страницы заказчику. Благодаря такому заполнителю было видно, сколько строчек помещается на странице, подходит ли дизайн шрифтов для данной книги.<br>
            <br><span>Откуда он появился?</span><br>
            В самом деле, волшебные слова Lorem ipsum известны многим из тех, кто работает в области полиграфии или же веб-дизайна. Более того, эта абракадабра — только начало большого текста, и существуют программы, которые сгенерируют продолжение якобы бессмыслицы на псевдолатыни, выдав необходимое число символов, абзацев или параграфов. Для чего? Только для того, чтобы заполнить место текстом, похожим на обычный текст, изображенным латинским алфавитом, но внимания читателя не отвлекающим. <br>
            <br><span>Откуда его взять?</span><br>
            Такую штуку специалисты по дизайну называют «рыбой». И хотя сейчас Lorem ipsum используют главным образом специалисты по веб-дизайну, придумана эта «рыба» была еще в 16-м веке книгопечатниками для демонстрации шрифтов различных форм и размеров. Чтобы заказчик видел, как будет выглядеть печатная страница, сколько на ней окажется строчек и подходит ли используемый шрифт для цели, с которой печатается заказываемая книга. Вот печатники взяли длинный латинский текст и применили для презентации.</p>
        </div>
        <footer><p class="copyright"> &copy; Копирайт 2017</p></footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

С `inline-block` есть одна старая технология, которорая называется "гусеничный код"... Заключается она в том, что нужно убрать пробелы между `inline-block`-ами, например с помощью комментариев... (и код с `-->...<!--` напоминает гусеницу с волосками). Ну а остальное дело техники. Нужно пересчитать ширины с учетом `margin`-ов и расположить в контейнере.

Так как вы спрашивали про `inline-block`, то мой ответ с учетом ваших пожеланий... Однако, я не рекомендую вам делать это в таком виде. Обратите внимание на технологию [FLEX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), которую сегодня поддерживают все современные браузеры. Здесь есть примеры:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
body{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .container{
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        .image{
            max-width: 980px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        img{
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        header{
            min-width:100%;
            background-color:#c2c2c2;
            margin:0;
        }
        .news_block{
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 980px;
            min-width: 720px;
            margin:0 auto;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .block-list {
            margin: 0 -10px;
        }
        .block{
            width: calc(25% - 20px);
            margin: 0 10px;
            height:170px;
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            position:relative;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
          button{
            width:170px;
            height:40px;
            border:none;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:130px;
            background-color:#68a4c4 ;
            color:white;
            font-weight: bold;
        
        }
        button:hover{
            background-color:grey;
        }
        h1{
            margin:0;
            text-align: center;
            padding:20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
       .main{
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
       }
        .news{
            padding:5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .description{
            margin:0;
            padding:20px 125px 30px 120px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        footer{
            width:100%;
            height:60px;
            background-color:#68a4c4;
            color:white;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .copyright{
            margin:0;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 760px) {
       
       .main{
          max-width:100%;  
          margin:0 auto;
       }
       .block{
          width:95%;
          height:170px;
          background-color:#f8f8f8;   
          margin-right: 0;
      } 
     
      button{
          width:100%;
          height:40px;
          border:none;
          position:absolute;
          left:0px;
          top:130px;
          background-color:#68a4c4 ;
          color:white;
          font-weight: bold;
      
      }
  
      .description{
          width:95%;
          margin:0;
          padding:10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body{
          position:relative;
      }
      header{
          width:100%;
    }

      footer{
          width:100%;
      }
      img{
          width:90%;
          height:auto;
      }
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <header>
         <h1>Новости для котиков</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="news_block">
        <div class="block-list"><!--
         --><div class="block ">
            <p class="main">Новость 1</p>
            <p class="news">Кому-то еще инресно узнать про короновирус?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
         </div><!--
         --><div class="block ">
            <p class="main"> Новость 2</p>
            <p class="news">Отменили минский полумарафон, зря готовились</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
         </div><!--
         --><div class="block ">
            <p class="main">Новость 3</p>
            <p class="news">Куда пойти на выходных когда нет денег?</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
         </div><!--
         --><div class="block ">
            <p class="main"> Новость 4</p>
            <p class="news">Погода испортилась, а чего вы хотели от Сентября</p>
            <button>Читать дальше</button>
         </div><!--
        --></div>
      </div>  
      <div class="container">
         <p class="description">
            <span>Что такое Lorem ipsum?</span><br>
            <br>Для заполнения страницы в веб-дизайне используют специально сгенерированный бессмысленный текст, получивший название Lorem ipsum. Перевод данной фразы в таком виде отсутствует, это искаженная цитата из труда Цицерона «О пределах добра и зла», написанного на латыни. Данное словосочетание — обрезка фразы «Dolorem ipsum», которая переводится как «саму боль».<br>
            <br><span>Почему он используется?</span><br>
            Использовать данный текст в книгопечатании начали еще 500 лет назад, чтобы продемонстрировать различные шрифты и внешний вид страницы заказчику. Благодаря такому заполнителю было видно, сколько строчек помещается на странице, подходит ли дизайн шрифтов для данной книги.<br>
            <br><span>Откуда он появился?</span><br>
            В самом деле, волшебные слова Lorem ipsum известны многим из тех, кто работает в области полиграфии или же веб-дизайна. Более того, эта абракадабра — только начало большого текста, и существуют программы, которые сгенерируют продолжение якобы бессмыслицы на псевдолатыни, выдав необходимое число символов, абзацев или параграфов. Для чего? Только для того, чтобы заполнить место текстом, похожим на обычный текст, изображенным латинским алфавитом, но внимания читателя не отвлекающим. <br>
            <br><span>Откуда его взять?</span><br>
            Такую штуку специалисты по дизайну называют «рыбой». И хотя сейчас Lorem ipsum используют главным образом специалисты по веб-дизайну, придумана эта «рыба» была еще в 16-м веке книгопечатниками для демонстрации шрифтов различных форм и размеров. Чтобы заказчик видел, как будет выглядеть печатная страница, сколько на ней окажется строчек и подходит ли используемый шрифт для цели, с которой печатается заказываемая книга. Вот печатники взяли длинный латинский текст и применили для презентации.
         </p>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <p class="copyright"> &copy; Копирайт 2017</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
```